# Как сгенерировать в Excel (Word...) в Visual Basic хеш (hash) самого файла в котором это происходит?

Tags: хеширование, visual-basic

Есть файл MS документа, скажем Excel и нужно при нажатии на кнопку, чтобы он вернул в буфер обмена хеш сумму именно этого файла, в котором эта вся история происходит в таком виде:
http://kakojto.site/hash-summa-etogo-faila

т.е. заданный статичный URL к которому он добавит эту хеш сумму.

ну и как вариант, чтобы это вообще выглядело как ссылка или кнопка, открывающая браузер

Comment: А Вас не смущает то, что в Офисный файл вносятся изменения практически на каждый чих? и что хэш уже в момент окончания вычисления запросто может быть невалидным?

Comment: идея в том, чтобы по клику получить именно текущий хеш. и далее по тексту (сделал новый чих, кликнул, получил новый хеш). плюс я хочу отработать такую логику, чтобы по клику на эту кнопку одновременно происходило сохранение файла, соответственно если файл вновь созданный, то выскочит диалог сохранения. ну, плюс пользователь имеет в арсенале возможности запретить вносить изменения файл МС документа. это какбы стандартный тул. даже можно пароль наложить